# build dependency on shared JavaScript file

Tags: maven, dependencies, build-process, javascript

**Context:**

- We use a third-party maven plugin to compile lesscss into css
  (lesscss-maven-plugin)
- We cannot modify or update this plugin.
- We cannot switch to another plugin, use grunt, or any other build
  tool.
- The plugin allows us to specify a JS file as a workaround to
  upgrading the plugin itself.
- Currently we have to have a copy of the
  file included with each and every project

**Question:**

How can the JS file be packaged and a build/compile time dependency defined in the POM so that the file can be shared across projects easily? 
Is it possible to use a URL for the file path instead of the {project.basedir}?

**Example POM Snippet:**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.lesscss</groupId>
    <artifactId>lesscss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/less</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/css</outputDirectory>
        <compress>true</compress>
        <includes>
            <include>example.less</include>
        </includes>
        <lessJs>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/lib/less-1.7.0.min.js</lessJs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```